# Is it possible to see which torrents a server/tracker is hosting?

Tags: bittorrent

A server is acting as a host/tracker for various torrent files; if I have a working torrent I can download from it.

Is there an easy way to see which other files it is tracking/hosting?

Comment: A reasonable guess it that it's 80% porn.

Comment: As much as I would have assumed so too reading the question, it's not, it's old game demos :)

Comment: @Telemachus, lol, i'd say closer to 90%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As far as I know it is not**, unless they have some sort of web-interface or a client application for that particular purpose.

***Note:*** Of course if you had access to the database or file the tracker software used to store info about the torrents it is tracking you could technically see what it was tracking. But that information isn't exactly user friendly or particularly readable. Of course it is possible to see what it is if you know what you are looking at, but what you are looking at most likely depends on tracker to tracker